# Golang Check File Pemrs Regarding Whom

Tags: linux, go, permissions

In golang besides the regular checking file permission attributes i.e. `owner exec`, `group exec` and `others exec`

What is the proper (standard tools?) solution to determine whether the file would be executable specifically for current process in regard of current user and groups her belongs to?

Thx!

Comment: With [`Access()`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sys/unix#Access) though there's an inherent race condition in that the file or its permissions, owner, etc. can be modified between testing and trying to execute it. The usual advice is to try to execute it and catch the failure case